# Several BSODs, different STOP codes, can't identify the source

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I'm having constant bsods on my desktop. These are from the past week. Why are they so inconsistent? I have no idea how to figure out what's wrong.

Here is a screenshot from BlueScreenView:

[image]
[*View full size*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17FyS.jpg)

Comment: copy the folder C:\Windows\Minidump to the desktop, zip that folder and upload the zip.

Comment: Here they are - http://www77.zippyshare.com/v/42237677/file.html

Comment: install the win7 SP1 and all updates. You're at the unpatched Win7 RTM from 2009!!

Comment: Well, didn't even realize that. Here's the BSOD report since updating: http://www76.zippyshare.com/v/10263676/file.html

Comment: update the network card driver yk62x64.sys. Also post pictures from the memory and SPD tab of this tool: http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html

Comment: Memory: http://i.imgur.com/iFNRk0Z.png  SPD: http://i.imgur.com/vfeIzfv.png

Comment: lower the RAM speed to 400MHz in the BIOS. The 533MHz Profile may not work all the time.

Comment: I'm not really sure which BIOS setting to change... it's been too long since I've played with it. I think everything is set to auto except for some voltages and the cpu ratio/fsb. Anyway the RAM is rated 1066MHz? I'm beginning to suspect that my Creative Audigy 2 ZS is responsible for a majority of the BSODs. I've updated a few other drivers including the Audigy, ASACPI, disabled a couple others... about to pull/uninstall the Audigy for a few days.

Comment: look into the advanced BIOS settings. 533MHz is too fast. Lower it to 400.

Comment: Well... found the BIOS setting, set the DRAM to 800MHz from 1006MHz (had it lowered from 1066 in the past)... also noticed a few other threads recommending the 1:1 FSB:DRAM ratio. I think it's been over 48 hours, so I'm pretty sure this is finally resolved. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RAM runs at 533MHz which can be problematically for the stability, because not all motherboards support EPP Profiles correctly.

Go into the BIOS and set the RAM speed to 400MHz and the PC will be stable again.