# Several BSOD screens with different stop codes - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I bought a new pc, few days ago. since I got it, my windows 10 crashed about 8 to 10 times already.
Each time I get a different stop code, the ones I got already was:

1. KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
2. SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
3. IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
4. MEMORY_MANAGMENT
5. DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION

All I could find is [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/699574/several-bsods-different-stop-codes-cant-identify-the-source), but I don't know if his answer is the same as mine, please tell me if it is, I'll add pictures of anything needed.

Thank you for your help, in advance, it is really important.

EDIT: I updated all drivers (motherboard, nvidia gpu), and I got a new stop code after it crashed again: POOL_CORRUPTION_IN_FILE_AREA

Comment: @dsstorefile You are absolutely right, but I have to use this pc now, and I thought maybe I could just fix everything, maybe it is a common issue, I really don't have time to bring them my pc. I will do it, if there is no other solution. thank you for your response anyway :)

Comment: As said, bring it back.  You should never get BSOD's like that unless there are problems with the hardware.

Comment: @headkase Ok.. I guess I will do that.. Thought I could get around it somehow and solve it.. But thanks anyway

Comment: I'm leaving this question open, If maybe someone will find an answer, or will help me find one. @headkase

Comment: Certainly return it before you have put much PII on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my RAM stick being faulty, replacing it solved the issue entirely.